# Get position of found string using Regexp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a big text and I'd like to remove everything before a certain string.

The problem is, there are several occurrences of that string in the text, and I want to decide which one is correct by later analyzing the found piece of text.
I can't include that analysis in a regular expression because of its complexity:

```
text = <<HERE
big big text
goes here
HERE

pos = -1

a = text.scan(/some regexp/im)
a.each do |m|
  s = m[0]

  # analysis of found string
  ...


  if ( s is good ) # is the right candidate
    pos = ??? # here I'd like to have a position of the found string in the text.

  end

end

result_text = text[pos..-1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$~.offset(n)` will give the position of the `n`-th part of a match.

Comment: Thanks!
I tried it and I have to place this line
pos = $~.offset(0)
as the first instruction in the loop a.each.

Comment: If you are further using regexes and fearing that that might replace the current `$~`, then you can save it to a variable: `m = $~` and use that. You don't have to put it at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should count how many occurrences there are in your big string then use [index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-index) to cut off all the occurrences that do not match the final pattern.